# how to make a mathematical operation in balloon_text with amCharts Flash

Tags: flash, division, amcharts

I'm doing a report with amCharts for flash. I need to show on the label  the value `{value}`, a number that is the result of dividing `({value} / 60)` but I do not know how. I have the following:

```
<balloon_text> <! [CDATA [{title}: {value} minuts]]> </ balloon_text>
```

I need the following:

```
<balloon_text> <! [CDATA [{title}: {value} minutes - ({value} / 60) hours]]> </ balloon_text>
```

But it is impossible to perform operations within balloon_text label.